# Java -- Enter The Name of Items and Output Total Price.

Tags: java

This program is an assignment that I was given in my intro to Java class.

Cleveland state university issues Viking card for staffs, faculty and students. Each member of CSU is allowed to purchase 1-10 items from the bookstore with varying discount rates. A list of items and their prices will be given on the next page. Write a program that allows the user to enter the items they’d like to purchase. Your program should validate the CSU Viking card ID and compute the gross and net total (after including the discount rate).

All the data I entered was given to me so no need to worry about that.

I'm looking for a more simple way other then using if statements for every item entered. In my head I'm trying to store the entered names into arrays then add the sum of the entered names together. I've discovered however that even though I assigned the values of the variables as doubles. The array doesn't output that right number it outputs the default value of the word.

ALSO bonus points will be given in class if I use methods but I'm not entirely comfortable with them yet so I figured I would try to stick to what I know.

I'm not asking for someone to do the program for me so I can turn it in as given to me but merely help figuring out methods possibly, and especially getting it to output a gross total ill be able to figure out the discounts and everything else

Right now im only working with the first for loop so entering 40000 will do the trick to get to the sum ive been trying to work with.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Assignment2 {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Please enter CSU I.D.");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int csuid = input.nextInt();
    int minvalue1 = 40000;
    int maxvalue1 = 59999;
    int minvalue2 = 60000;
    int maxvalue2 = 79999;
    int minvalue3 = 80000;
    int maxvalue3 = 89999;
    int i;
    double bookbag = 40.00;
    double textbook = 50.00;
    double notebook = 3.00;
    double pen = 1.00;
    double pencil = 1.00;
    double sweatpants = 35.00;
    double shirt = 25.00;
    double sweater = 30.00;
    double candy = 2.00;
    double planner = 15.00;
    double sum = 0;
    System.out.println("Please enter how many items you are going to purchase.");
    int items = input.nextInt();
    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
    if (items <= 10)
    {
            String itemArray[];
            itemArray = new String[items];
            if (csuid >= minvalue1 && csuid <= maxvalue1)
                {
                for(i = 0; i < items; i++ )
                    {
                            System.out.println("What would you like to purchase?");
                            String c = read.next();
                            itemArray[i] = c;

                    }
                for(int counter = 0;counter < itemArray.length; counter++)
                            {
                                System.out.println(itemArray[counter] + " ");
                            }
                    System.out.println("Total Value " + sum);
                }
            else if (csuid >= minvalue2 && csuid <= maxvalue2)
                {
                for(i = 0; i < items; i++ )
                    {
                            System.out.println("What would you like to purchase?");
                            String c = read.next();
                            itemArray[i] = c;
                            for(int counter = 0;counter < itemArray.length; counter++)
                            {
                                System.out.println(itemArray[counter] + " ");
                                //sum += itemArray[counter];
                            }
                            System.out.println("Total Value " + sum);
                    }
                System.out.println("Total Value " + sum);
                }
            else if (csuid >= minvalue3 && csuid <= maxvalue3)
                {
                for(i = 0; i < items; i++ )
                    {
                            System.out.println("What would you like to purchase?");
                            String c = read.next();
                            itemArray[i] = c;
                            for(int counter = 0;counter < itemArray.length; counter++)
                            {
                                System.out.println(itemArray[counter] + " ");
                                //sum += itemArray[counter];
                            }
                            System.out.println("Total Value " + sum);
                    }
                System.out.println("Total Value " + sum);
                }
            else
                {
                    System.out.println("Invalid CSU ID");
                }
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Cannot purchase " + items + " items");
    }
    read.close();
    input.close();
}
```

}

Comment: Where are you ever accumulating a sum value?

Comment: Keep in mind that you cannot add values from `String itemArray[];` to `double sum`

Comment: Regarding methods, notice how you're doing the same thing in those `else-if` statements? That's where a method would come into play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding checking a valid CSU ID, you should combine the conditions using OR.

```
if ((min1<=id && id <= max1) || 
   (min2<=id && id <= max2)) {

} else {}  // Not valid
```

You can make a method called `isValidId(int id, int min, int max)`, but I'll leave that up to you.

Anyways, looks like you need a `Map<String, Double>`

For example,

```
Map<String, Double> amounts = new HashMap<>();
amounts.put("bookbag",  40.00);
amounts.put("textbook", 50.00);
...
```

Then, to add values, read from the Scanner, and store in the array, then get its value

```
for(int i = 0; i < items; i++ ) {
    System.out.println("What would you like to purchase?");
    String c = read.nextLine();
    itemArray[i] = c;
    sum += amounts.get(c);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, Ive added that into my program, but it's giving me an error saying "map cannot be resolved"